# Polymer paper-icon-button won't fire click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, polymer

I have installed Polymer 1.0 for use with my site. I have a paper-icon-button element within a paper-toolbar element. However, the paper-icon-button will not fire any events. Here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!-- Declare meta -->
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="author" content="TickerOfTime">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Load jQuery 2.1.4 -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Load jQueryUI 1.11.4 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"> <!-- Load jQueryUI CSS 1.11.4 -->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,600|Ubuntu|Poiret+One|Source+Code+Pro:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Load Fonts (Roboto:400(600), Ubuntu:400, Poiret One:400, Source Code Pro:300l) -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/prettify.css"> <!-- Load Prettifier CSS -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/prettify.js"></script> <!-- Load Prettifier JS -->
      <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Load JavaScript -->
      <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Load CSS -->
      <link rel="icon" href="images/rcpanel.png"> <!-- Load favicon -->
      <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Load polyfill support -->
    <!--                          Load Polymer/Iron here                                -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Iron-Icon -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Iron-Icons -->
    <!--                          Load Polymer Gold here                                -->
      <link rek="import" href="bower_components/gold-email-input/gold-email-input.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Gold-Email-Input -->
    <!--                          Load Polymer Molecules here                           -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/marked-element/marked-element.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Marked -->
    <!--                          Load Polymer Paper here                               -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Material -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-behaviors/paper-button-behavior.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Behaviors -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Button -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Icon-Button -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Input -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Spinner -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Radio-Button -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Toast -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Radio-Group -->
      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html"> <!-- Load Polymer Paper-Toolbar -->
      <title>RCPanel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <paper-material elevation="2" class="Paper" id="SideBarPaper" layered>

    </paper-material>
    <paper-material elevation="1" class="Paper" id="MainPaper">
        <paper-toolbar id="MenuBar">
            <paper-icon-button src="bower_components/material-design-icons/navigation/2x_web/ic_menu_white_36dp.png" id="MainMenuButton" class="MenuButton"></paper-icon-button>
                <div id="MenuDiv">
                        <p class="Headline">Welcome to RCPanel</p>
                </div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <p>This is the development of RCPanel.<br />If you would like to help with this project, or test it, click <a href="https://github.com/RCPanel/main">here</a>.</p>
        <paper-toast text="You clicked the menu button!" id="ClickToast"></paper-toast>
    </paper-material>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript code is such.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
prettyPrint();
var ButtonToast = $("#ClickToast");
var MenuButton = $("#MainMenubutton");
function ShowToast(Object) {
    Object.show();
};
MenuButton.on("tap",function() {
    ShowToast(ButtonToast);
});
});
```

I have tried on-tap, onclick, click, tap, all the events I can think of that were given. Is there something I have set up incorrectly, or is the event completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically code which your using is not Javascript, it is jquery.

so, attach the following tag at top after webcomponents-lite.js.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

This should work.

-- **Update** --

In this way code is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="//polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://kasperpeulen.github.io/PolymerElements/all.html">
<link rel="import" href="//elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<paper-material elevation="1" class="Paper" id="MainPaper">
  <paper-toolbar id="MenuBar">
    <paper-icon-button src="bower_components/material-design-icons/navigation/2x_web/ic_menu_white_36dp.png" onclick="displaytost()" id="MainMenuButton" class="MenuButton"></paper-icon-button>
    <div id="MenuDiv">
      <p class="Headline">Welcome to RCPanel</p>
    </div>
  </paper-toolbar>
  <p>This is the development of RCPanel.<br />
    If you would like to help with this project, or test it, click <a href="https://github.com/RCPanel/main">here</a>.</p>
  <paper-toast text="You clicked the menu button!" id="ClickToast"></paper-toast>
</paper-material>
<paper-toast id="hello"
                 duration="6000"
                 text="Hello World"> </paper-toast>
<script>
function displaytost(){
  document.querySelector('#hello').show();
  console.log("button Clicked")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Test Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OTHfqsqpxbBy4w9UnXEF?p=preview)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I should have noted that. That section is just the icon part. I am importing jQuery.

Comment: Roughly yes. The script is external and the imports are on my server. I'm sorry, I should have posted all my code.

Comment: Please edit you question by posting all necessary code.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OTHfqsqpxbBy4w9UnXEF?p=preview Please check this.Everything working fine in this way.

Comment: Yes. That works. Is there a way to make it work via external script?

Comment: No external script needed it is via javascript.

Comment: I know that. But is it possible for it to work with `<script src="../script.js"></script` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I made other example for you using it check here. http://plnkr.co/edit/OTHfqsqpxbBy4w9UnXEF?p=preview

Comment: Oh. Maybe it was the way I set it up. Thanks then!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var MenuButton = $("#MainMenubutton").click(function(){
   document.querySelector('#ClickToast').show();`
});
```

polymer v1.0

add paper-icon-button tag

onclick="document.querySelector('#ClickToast').show()"

```
<paper-material elevation="1" class="Paper" id="MainPaper">
    <paper-toolbar id="MenuBar">
        <paper-icon-button src="bower_components/material-design-icons/navigation/2x_web/ic_menu_white_36dp.png" id="MainMenuButton" class="MenuButton" onclick="document.querySelector('#ClickToast').show()"></paper-icon-button>
            <div id="MenuDiv">
                    <p class="Headline">Welcome to RCPanel</p>
            </div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <p>This is the development of RCPanel.<br />If you would like to help with this project, or test it, click <a href="https://github.com/RCPanel/main">here</a>.</p>
    <paper-toast text="You clicked the menu button!" id="ClickToast"></paper-toast>
</paper-material>
```

Comment: Are you trying to fix the toast showing or the button firing? I'm not at a place where I can try this right now, and I've gotten rusty with jQuery.

Comment: I have tried this and Gowthamraj's code. It apparently only connects with the click event when the script is an internal tag. External script does not work. However, it would be much better if the external would work.